# Authenticate users to view files from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Good Day Everybody,

I'm fairly new to AWS, and I have a problem right now. I'm not even sure if this is something that is possible with S3. I tried googling it, but couldn't find any proper response (Probably because the keywords I searched doesn't make much sense ;) ).

So my problem is this, I have an node application which uploads user images to S3. I wan't to know how to properly access this images later in the front-end(Some sort of direct link). But at the same time, I should be able to restrict the users who can access the image. For eg: If user xyz uploads an image only that user should be able to see it. Another user say abc tries to open the direct link, it should say access restricited or something similar.

Or if that is not possible, atleast I should be able to put an encrypted timestamp on the get url, so that the image will be accessible through that particular url for only a limited amount of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical use case for S3 Pre-signed URLs.

In S3, you are able to specify some query strings on the URL of your object that include an Access Key, an expiration timestamp and a signature. S3 validates the signature and checks if the request has been made before the expiration timestamp. If that's the case, it will serve the object. Otherwise, it will return an error.

The AWS SDK for JavaScript (Node.js) includes an example on how to generate pre-signed URLs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Getting_a_pre-signed_URL_for_a_getObject_operation__getSignedUrl_